# Nestjs param validation doesn't throw with ValidationPipe tranform

Tags: nestjs

NestJs has all these edgecases and finally I found best case for to try and serialize all data without much hassle and throw an error if the data cannot be serialized, using this:

```
app.useGlobalPipes(
  new ValidationPipe({
    transform: true,
    transformOptions: { enableImplicitConversion: true },
  }),
);
```

All good so far, I can remove a bunch of decorators now, except that if I have something similar to this example from their own documentation where they talk about the benefits of transform, if the value is a string it doesn't throw, it just sets the number to NaN! Why???

```
@Get(':id')
findOne(@Param('id') id: number) {
  console.log(typeof id === 'number'); // true
  return 'This action returns a user';
}
```

Why do I have to explicitly tell it what pipe to use on each request when the whole point of transform is that it tries to convert or throw so you don't have to tell it explicitly, which it does for DTOs properties but not for params. Honestly, can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the value is a string it doesn't throw, it just sets the number to NaN! Why???

Because that's specifically how `class-transformer` and the JavaScript `Number` constructor work. If you pass `Number('hello world')` you get back `NaN` which has a `typeof` equal to `number`. *Technically* it works within the bounds of JavaScript.

[According to class-tranformer's docs](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer?tab=readme-ov-file#implicit-type-conversion) the `enableImplicitConversion` option

> Enables automatic conversion between built-in types based on type information provided by Typescript.

If you want to perform *actual* validation on the id you should create a DTO class and use the proper `class-validator` decorators like so:

```js
export class IdParamDto {
  @IsInt()
  id: number
}
```

And now you can use it with your route handler like

```js
@Get(':id')
findOne(@Param() {id}: IdParamDto) {
  console.log(typeof id === 'number'); // true
  return 'This action returns a user';
}
```

> Why do I have to explicitly tell it what pipe to use on each request when the whole point of transform is that it tries to convert or throw

Because that's not the point of `class-transformer`. That's the point of `class-validator`. Nest's `ValidationPipe` makes use of **both** because the incoming object will not be a class instance by default and as such `class-validator` will have nothing to validate against, no metadata to try and work with. So what the pipe does with your options is it sees that the value coming in is a string, but typescript says it's a number, class-transformer recognizes this and transforms the string to a number, even an "invalid" one because that's how JS works,and then the pipe sees that `transform: true` is set so it returns the transformed value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get that. It just seems like false advertisement. The way the code is written in documentation is not good for real work as it is filled with issues.